# How to visualize a graph from DGL's datasets?

Tags: python, graph, pytorch, data-visualization, dgl

The following snippet comes from the tutorial https://cnvrg.io/graph-neural-networks/. How can I visualize a graph from the `dataset`? Using something like `matplotlib` if possible.

```py
import dgl
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import dgl.data
dataset = dgl.data.CoraGraphDataset()
g = dataset[0]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import dgl.data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

dataset = dgl.data.CoraGraphDataset()
g = dataset[0]
options = {
    'node_color': 'black',
    'node_size': 20,
    'width': 1,
}
G = dgl.to_networkx(g)
plt.figure(figsize=[15,7])
nx.draw(G, **options)
```

It is a huge graph so you might have to play with the sizes (node, width, figure, etc.).
Here are some useful links:

- https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html
- https://docs.dgl.ai/en/0.5.x/generated/dgl.to_networkx.html#dgl.to_networkx
- https://docs.dgl.ai/en/0.5.x/api/python/dgl.data.html

Comment: don't know if it's on purpose but you are missing the last line "plt.show()" :)

Comment: My code works when drawing to an interactive display. Note that you may need to issue a Matplotlib

plt.show()  
command if you are not using matplotlib in interactive mode.